# Galería Dinámica con Fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, plugin

Buenas, Estoy creando una app en Cordova, que al dar con el dedo cargue la galería de los productos de forma dinámica, Pero tengo un problema, he intentado de mil formas y no consigo la solución la consola me devuelve `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function` Lo curioso es que funcionaba de forma clasica que al dar click en una imagen, se cargaba el plugin, pero lo necesito trabajar a código ya que mando las peticiones al servidor y luego ejecutar la galería, por lo que necesito usar la función, he intentado de mil maneras y sigue apareciéndome ese mismo error.

```js
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
                function(){                    
                    $.ajax({
                       url:'http://www.ebabylist.es/appstore/extra/view/load_product_gallery.php'+window.location.search,
                       method:'GET',
                       cache:false,
                       success:function(fancy_gallery){ // Traer las imagenes del servidor
                           $("#cache_gallery").html(fancy_gallery);
                           $("div[data-bind=json_gallery]").click(
                                   function(){
                                    $().fancybox({ //aqui es donde dispara el error
                                    selector : '[data-fancybox="images"]',
                                    loop     : true
                                  });
                                   });
                       },
                       error:function(data){
                           console.log(data);
                           alert("Error al intentar cargar la galeria de este producto");
                       }
                    });
                });

    </script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  
  <div data-bind="json_gallery" id="json_photo" class="mSCover"></div><!-- Aqui debe dispararse el evento click -->
  <div id="cache_gallery" style="display:none"></div><!-- IMAGENES TRAIDAS DEL SERVIDOR-->
```

y este es mi codigo del servidor

```js
    private function fancy($prod_galery){
        $statement = "SELECT * FROM galeria WHERE producto_id = :producto";
        try{
            $msg = $this->BBDD->prepare($statement);
            $msg->bindValue(":producto", htmlentities(addslashes($prod_galery)));
            $msg->execute();
            if($msg->rowCount()!=0){
               foreach($msg->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) as $fancy){
                   echo "                        
                         <a class='load_fancy' href='http://www.ebabylist.es/appstore/img/{$fancy->foto_nombre}' data-caption='img' data-type='image' data-fancybox='images'>
                        <img src='http://www.ebabylist.es/appstore/img/{$fancy->foto_nombre}' />
                         </a>
                        ";

               }
            }else{
               die("No se encuentra imagenes asociadas con este producto");
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die('Fail to read this message' . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . ' ' . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }finally{
            
        }       
    }
```

No veo ningún error en el código pero no se porque no me funciona.
http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#usage

Comment: Por el error que recibes parece que no se esta cargando el archivo `js/jquery.fancybox.min.js`. ¿Has validado que dicho archivo se este copiando al hacer el `build`?

Comment: Si, tambien intente hacerlo por cdns cargando en un script externo, e igual parece que no carga el archivo